# How to prove the left side of this inequalities?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

> How to prove the left side of this inequalities ?
>   $$\frac{-|z|}{1+|z|}\leq {\bf Re}\left\{\int_{0}^{z}\left(\frac{\mu(s)}{s(1-s)(1-\mu(s))}\right) ds\right\}\leq \frac{|z|}{1-|z|},$$
>   where $\mu(z)$ is analytic in the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ with $\mu(0)=0$ and $|\mu(z)|\leq |z|<1,\, z\in \mathbb{D}$.

We first prove the right side:

Because $\mu(0)=0$ and $|\mu(z)|\leq |z|<1$, for $|z|=r$, we have
$$
\left|\frac{\mu(z)}{z(1-\mu(z))}\right|\leq\frac{1}{1-r}\quad and\quad
\left|\frac{1}{1-z}\right|\leq\frac{1}{1-r},
$$
which implies that
$${\bf Re}\left\{\int_{0}^{z}\left(\frac{\mu(s)}{s(1-s)(1-\mu(s))}\right) ds\right\}\leq\int_{0}^{r}\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}dt= \frac{r}{1-r}.$$

But I don't know how to prove the left side.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Take $\mu(s)=0$ why should the left inequality hold?

Comment: $\mu(z)\neq 0$ only $\mu(0)=0$